# DIY electronic doorbell keeps blowing up my cheap eBay car amplifier

Tags: amplifier, speakers

I'm trying to make a DIY electronic doorbell with two speakers (one is nearby but the other is 20 metres away, connected by a solid copper 14 awg cable).

It incorporates a timer to turn on the sytem when the doorbell is pushed, and plays a 10-second MP3 from a USB memory stick before shutting off.

It worked fine but soon seemed to blow a channel on the amp (cheap eBay car amplifier).

My first attempt used 2 channels on a 4-channel amp. After it failed, I used the other 2 channels instead, and it blew another one. I bought a different 2-channel amp, but same problem.
I suspect that the problem is due to one speaker having too much resistance due to its long cable

Any ideas?.................>>

Thank you for the inputs.  The first amp I used was like this one.......  https://www.ebay.com/itm/185002613802?hash=item2b1303dc2a:g:KbEAAOSwQpdfCM4g

Sorry, but I don't understand what DC offset is . (I'm a newbie with only a multimeter for tools)

Comment: Is there a DC offset in your audio?

Comment: _"cheap eBay car amplifier."_ - can you give us any information about the amp and what is inside it? eg. model number, specs, photo of pcb, amplifier IC part numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what  DC offset is . (I'm a newbie with only a multimeter for tools)

Answer (score 2):

You can rule out "too much resistance" - first off, the 20 (40 round trip) meters of cable is still only an ohm or so, and secondly, audio amps will blow when the load is too LOW, not too high.

Things I would check :

1. check wiring VERY carefully for shorts (possibly intermittent)
2. check impedance of the speakers is not too low for the amps
3. check that the amps have adequate heatsinking for the power you are trying to deliver (likely not a problem as I guess the tone is only momentary)
4. check if there is DC coming out of the amps even when there is no signal - in fact check all signals with a scope, including power rails.

Comment: The first amp I used was like this one.......  https://www.ebay.com/itm/185002613802?hash=item2b1303dc2a:g:KbEAAOSwQpdfCM4g

Comment: The amp specifies 4- 16 Ω